# Chromecast and casting PDFs

Tags: ios, performance, pdf, chromecast

I am not very good at coding but I would very much like some Chromecast enabled app and Chrome-app which would allow me to Cast PDFs to my Chromecast. The reason for this is that I would like to use Chromecast for LaTeX beamer presentations and PDF-versions of PowerPoint presentations.
Now you might say that I could simply just open a PDF in a tab and then cast this tab to a Chromecat. But sadly I have had three kinds of troubles with this solution.

1. It is a slow solution. It forces me to mirror my screen which demands (relatively) many ressources from my computer. And my computer needs to be on all the time for the PDF to be shown. If I instead send the PDF to the Chromecast, my computer or phone would only have to work as a remote.
2. It only works with Chrome. I cannot display PDFs from my iPhone with this solution.
3. It actually does not work. Every time I have tried to mirror a PDF, the document freezes at some point on my television. I can continue to scroll, but I cannot scroll what is shown on my TV.

I imagine that it is not very complicated to make such an app. I imagine that it ought to be possible to make a Chromecast receiver app based on the PDF.js project in order to ensure the reading capabilities on the Chromecast. In general it would be nice to just send all sorts of presentations to the Chromecast - whether it be PDFs, PowerPoint and what not. Am I the only one who would like such a capability?

Comment: Yes, it would be great to have? Not sure what you're asking. The Google Slides app is cast-enabled and I wouldn't be surprised if the Powerpoint app is too. If you want to write your own application that does it, great. One thing to probably keep in mind is that, I believe Cast doesn't read local content, it uses a reference of the content hosted somewhere on the web. So you'll need to get your pdfs somewhere, maybe Google Drive, to have your receiver load it.

Comment: Google Slides is made by Google. So for semi obvious reasons, it has casting enabled. Powerpoint is made by Microsoft. So for semi obvious reason, it does not have casting enabled.

I am asking for an app that casts PDFs. It would be great to be able to cast files in Dropbox for instance.

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask for apps. If you need some place to start for writing your own, I suggest you work off one of the [samples from GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast).